# "new operator" to instantiate another class as a factory?

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator

I try to use the `new` operator to instantiate a specific class and not the one behind the `new` keyword.

I try to have a kind of "factory" for an abstract class.

It seems to me that it is not possible, but lets double check !
This code compile, but the main code treat it as a `Test` (and not a `TestImpl` class)

```
class Test
{
public:
  virtual int testCall() { return 0; };

  static void* operator new(std::size_t);
};

class TestImpl : public Test
{
  virtual int testCall() override
  {
    return i;
  }

  int i = 15;
};

void* Test::operator new(size_t sz)
{
  return ::new TestImpl();
}

void main()
{
  Test * t = new Test(); // Call the new operator, correctly
  int i = test->testCall(); // i == 0 and not 15
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just have a static function called `create` that'll return a pointer to a new `Test`?

Comment: @tobi303 I think the implicit question is quite clearly 'Why does the main function treat it as a "Test" and not a TestImpl" class as OP expected?'

Comment: @ChrisDrew might be. Could also be "How to make the main function treat it as a `TestImpl`?" which is a slightly different question that requires a different answer. Could also be "How to use operator new as a factory?" as the title suggests. Anyhow, sometimes I am just too nitpicky ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that for every [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), the two following things will be performed:

1. allocate memory via appropriate `operator new`.
2. construct the object on the memory allocated by step#1.

So `operator new` only allocates memory, doesn't construct the object. That means, for `Test * t = new Test();`, still a `Test` will be constructed, on the memory allocated by the overloaded `operator new`; even you constructed a `TestImpl` inside the `operator new`, but it'll be overwritten on the same memory soon, after the `operator new` finished.

Comment: I have a follow up question: Is the example code the OP provided, defined behaviour? The memory is allocated using a classic `new`, and then instantiated by the `TestImpl()` constructor, and then later overridden by the `Test()` constructor. Will everything get deleted safely afterwards? I believe not, if the TestImpl class is larger and allocates extra memory (like a std::vector).

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux You're right, of course not. And when the pointer is `delete`ed, only the destructor of `Test` will be invoked.

Comment: This is nicely descibed in chapter "11.2.3 Getting Memory Space" of "The C++ Programming Language" by B. Stroustrup.

Comment: Thanks, I know why and how it work, but my concern is to find a way to bypass this behavior. I think it it not possible. The final goal is to hide the full object implementation (PImpl, even the derivated model) are not satisfying me, so I try to find an elegant solution with an abstract class !

Comment: You can just make the base class un-instantiatable (private/protected-only constructors) and force the use of a static factory function. That can do whatever it wants, including creating a derived class local to a non-inlined translation unit.

Comment: @CDZ Well I would say it's the wrong way for implementing that.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux You are free to reuse memory that was used to allocate another type, but the destructor is not (guaranteed to be) called, and following pointers/references to data in old instance is undefined behavior.  There may be caviets if the class you initially allocated contained `const` data as well, uncertain.

Comment: @CDZ Are you just doing this for fun?  It's fun to bend a compiler to your will, but in most cases, it's better to be conservative.  Remember, in most cases someone else will have to look at/use your code.  The factory pattern is a well recognized idiom that has been used in thousands of programs over decades.  Don't underestimate it's elegance.